# HttpRequest::getRequestHeaders only seems to return a subset of headers?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

As you can see, i did a request which was successful.  The issue I have is the 3 lined i have printed out below.

```
var headerList = request.getAllResponseHeaders();
print("RunTime type of Header List: ${headerList.runtimeType}");
print("Header List Count: ${headerList.length}");
print("Header List is as follows: \n$headerList");
```

So it seems that request, a `HttpRequest` is not returning enough information.  I was hoping it woudl return either a complete string of all header infomration, a Map of k=>v pairs, or an array.

Seems like it only fetched the first 64 characters.

Why would it not get all of the files?  Ideally, I am trying to get the "Content-Disposition" header, by way of `request.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition");` but as you can imagine, given this information, it actually will return null, since the request cant find that information.

[image]

Comment: What do the print statements print?

Comment: You see them below in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to add

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` `Content-Disposition`

on your server.

> `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` (optional) - The XMLHttpRequest 2 object
>   has a `getResponseHeader()` method that returns the value of a
>   particular response header. During a CORS request, the
>   `getResponseHeader()` method can only access simple response headers.
>   Simple response headers are defined as follows:
>
> - Cache-Control
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type
> - Expires
> - Last-Modified
> - Pragma
>
> If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you
>   have to use the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header. The value of
>   this header is a comma-delimited list of response headers you want to
>   expose to the client.

From http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Was offline, sorry for the delay.  Interesting.  I mean, you can see they are in fact returned by the server, since they are in my response no?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what " ... want clients to be able to access other headers ..." means but The headers you got are listed and the ones you didn't get are not listed. IMHO it wouldn't make sense to send such headers to the browser if they are supposed to be blocked by the server.

Comment: A colleague created a dart hack for downloading a file from a restful end point, requiring a bearer token to access, so he grabs it, and then checks the disposition to make sure the file has a name... and if not, it would set a default name for it.    I think the issue I am currently facing is that You can see by the resonse, the disposition is fetched and in the response, but the HttpResponse doesnt seems to print out all of the headers, by way of the `request.getAllResponseHeaders();` call which is printed out

Comment: I know that already. Did you try to add the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header on your server for the headers you want to access?

Comment: Im going to request the colleague to open it up and ensure it.  It is just weird that the dart class doesnt process what is visible.  Maybe there is something going on, but i will follow up with you when he lets me know.

Comment: Because if the header is not provided, the browser doesn't make it available to JS (hence Dart).

Comment: It now works.   I did need to make sure that line is in fact added.  Thank you.